# android getDefaultSharedPreferences doesn't get applied

Tags: android

I'm new to android development and recently i'm working on fixing bugs. The app shouldn't load the previous preference but it does load it up instead of loading the default values.

Here is what i have in Main Activity

```
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
    // register listener for SharedPreferences changes
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);

        QuizFragment quizFragment = (QuizFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.quizFragment);
        quizFragment.updateGuessRows(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
        quizFragment.updateRegions(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
        quizFragment.updateNumberQuestions(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
```

and here is my full code https://github.com/jamin567/android

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
 final String eulaKey = "mykey";
    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    mPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(eulaKey, true);
    editor.commit();
```

in which case you can specify your own preferences file name (myAppPrefs) and can control access persmission to it. Other operating modes include: **MODE_WORLD_READABLE, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, MODE_MULTI_PROCESS**